# ngTemplateOutlet : event handler fails

Tags: angular, angular2-template

[EDIT]
Added stackblitz repro :https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-outlet-7ivu6e?file=app/grid/grid.component.ts

In my component I use `ngTemplateOutlet` to dynamically change the content of some part of the component view :

```
     <ng-template #defaultExpanderTemplate>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-0 text-left"
                    (click)="toggleRow(dataItem, 'id'); toggleButton(dataItem.id)"
                    [ngClass]="{'toggled': toggledButtons[dataItem.id]}">
                    <i class="fas fa-chevron-down mr-2"></i>
                    {{dataItem[col.displayField] || dataItem[col.field]}}
                </button>
            </ng-template>
            <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="expanderTemplate || defaultExpanderTemplate"
                [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: dataItem }">
            </ng-container>
```

`toggleRow`, and `toggleButton` event handlers are defined in my Component.

Now I define the `expanderTemplate` where my Component is actually used:

```
<my-component>
  <ng-template #expanderTemplate let-dataItem>

   <div class="color-tag" [ngClass]="dataItem.colorTag"> 
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-0 text-left"
        (click)="toggleRow(dataItem, 'id'); toggleButton(dataItem.id)"
        [ngClass]="{'toggled': toggledButtons[dataItem.id]}">
        <i class="fas fa-chevron-down mr-2"></i>
        {{dataItem[col.displayField] || dataItem[col.field]}}
    </button>
   </div> 
</ng-template>
</my-component>
```

Note that this template, simply adds a `div` element around the button that was used in the defaulTemplate above. Maybe there is a better way to do this  ?

Now the events are not known from the calling component and I get the exception in the consol :

ERROR TypeError: ctx_r12.toggleRow is not a function

I understand it, but then how do I achieve this  ?

Comment: Could you post a minimal example on Stackblitz?

Comment: I've added the repro on StackBlitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-outlet-7ivu6e?file=app/grid/grid.component.ts  If you click the button, you will see the error in console

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to call `grid.toggleRow` (and same for other functions)

Comment: The answer is not clear. The repro on StackBlitz doesn't have a `grid` variable anywhere.